# Wireframes of landmarks

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective, wireframing

I found these wireframe vector graphics of a few landmarks and was wondering how they were created. I doubt it was done by hand, so what kind of techniques are there to create this kind of graphic?

I found both files with an online search on a Chinese site. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pw59rw2ld1ifx6t/AABby4Ofp04q01g4Rz0Jp9VQa?dl=0) they are in their source format (ai).

[image: golden gate bridge]

[image: eiffel]

Comment: It looks like 3D modeling from a drafting program to me.

Comment: I agree with Webster.. probably a 3D model rendered wireframe. Although it *could* [absolutely be done by hand](http://www.khulsey.com/).

Comment: Usually, does the wireframe procedure create all the tiny lines inside the overall shape? What kind of software would you recommend to create something along these lines?

Comment: but 3D is done by hand.

Answer (score 1):

They are wireframe renderings of 3D models, more exactly = 2D renderings of wireframes, hidden lines removed. Pro level 3D software exports scenes like these as 2D vector images.

Famous objects like Golden Gate and Eiffel Tower are widely available as free and paid models in several formats. Search for "3D Golden Gate bridge" and see yourself.

There exists much variety in

- general accuracy
- how much surrounding terrain is included and is it realistic
- resolution
- which details are 3D models and which are only texture images
- file format

Trimble SketchUP is one popular easy to use 3D program. It has a wide cloud library (=3D warehouse) of uploaded models that other users can download. These 2 objects with reduced surrounding terrains were both available in several versions, some of them even were good. Unfortunately free version of SketcUP doesn't make vector wireframe renderings, only bitmaps. The same seems to be tried generally in free versions of commercial 3D software (= not too much for free).

I have met a piece of 3D freeware that refuses to export 2D renderings in any Illustrator compatible vector format (=disabled, available in paid version), but it's PDF output is an Illustrator compatible vector image. I tried to import and render a SketchUP model of Golden Gate for this answer, but that freeware has a model complexity limit which dropped off half of the bridge.

In 3D model marketplaces your example object cost about $20,- each

You need also models for the surrounding terrain. Rudimentary terrain without complex details  is created in 3D software in few minutes. Paris around Eiffel Tower created from scratch takes days. Inserting some library trees and houses is done fast.

If you like to do something like these images starting from 3D models you must have

- the right 3D software to use the model and
- skills beyond the full novice level to make the needed modifications and renderings.

If you are new in 3D, start with easy freebie such as SketchUP. After you know it, not before, you are ready for harder pieces such as Blender, Maya, 3DsMax, Rhinoceros etc...

Competent training, an incredible luck or brains of a genius can make possible to get anything useful done in complex programs straight in the beginning without solid background of simpler software.